# Replace() does not find dates and does not convert to another string

Tags: python, pandas

I have an array in csv:

```
    date        group
0   2015-01-02  WODKA
1   2015-01-02  PIWO
2   2015-01-02  2015-01-02
3   2015-01-03  WODKA
4   2015-01-03  PIWO
5   2015-01-03  2015-01-03
6   2015-01-03  WODKA
7   2015-01-03  PIWO
```

And I would like to convert all the dates from the column "group" to the word "sum". But my code does not work...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime as dt

x = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\dell\\Desktop\\list_1.csv", sep=';')
x.group = x.group.replace(dt, 'sum')
```

Comment: Why do you *think* that would work? `dt` is a `module` object, do you have a bunch of references to the `dt` module -object in your `group` column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we can update those rows where we could convert `group` to `datetime`:

```
In [40]: df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['group'], errors='coerce').notnull(), 'group'] = 'sum'

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
         date  group
0  2015-01-02  WODKA
1  2015-01-02   PIWO
2  2015-01-02    sum
3  2015-01-03  WODKA
4  2015-01-03   PIWO
5  2015-01-03    sum
6  2015-01-03  WODKA
7  2015-01-03   PIWO
```

or using RegEx (NOTE: first solution is much more flexible as it'll support different date formats):

```
In [46]: df['sum'] = df['group'].str.replace(r'^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', 'sum')

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
         date       group    sum
0  2015-01-02       WODKA  WODKA
1  2015-01-02        PIWO   PIWO
2  2015-01-02  2015-01-02    sum
3  2015-01-03       WODKA  WODKA
4  2015-01-03        PIWO   PIWO
5  2015-01-03  2015-01-03    sum
6  2015-01-03       WODKA  WODKA
7  2015-01-03        PIWO   PIWO
```

Comment: Works great, that was it! There are still many lessons ahead of me :) Thanks!

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski, glad i could help :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski I will suggested you ***accept*** MaxU's answer instead of mine  ,since it is well documented by pandas API , if you like my answer you can ***upvote*** . We need to consider the future visitors and bring them to the 100% right answer.

Comment: @Wen, thank you! I think it's up to OP to chose the best answer. :) PS you have my upvote already...

Comment: @Wen ok zrobione :)

Comment: @TomaszPrzemski, it's not necessarry! If you think Wen's answer is better for - please accept his answer. :)

Comment: @MaxU Man, you are using safety way , mine just a source code ,definitely your is better ~ :-)

Comment: @MaxU Only justice, because in my project I used your solution :)

Comment: @Wen, OK, i'm going to bed now. I wish you happy answering! :)

Answer (score 4):

Or do some trick with special mark `-`( Notice , I will recommend MaxU's answer)

```
df.group.replace({'-':np.nan},regex=True).fillna('sum')
Out[449]: 
0    WODKA
1     PIWO
2      sum
3    WODKA
4     PIWO
5      sum
6    WODKA
7     PIWO
Name: group, dtype: object
```

Comment: This reminds me of our last discussion that prompted a question in itself :). Where _are_ you learning these tricks, I've not seen anything like them when I'm searching for my own problems?

Comment: Source code, not docs, then? Do they explicitly state as comments in the source code that such approaches will give the desired results, or do you identify these approaches yourself from understanding the code?

Comment: @roganjosh https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L3678-L3926

Comment: I've found both examples really cool in that they make me question the inner workings, but I have to be honest that I would find the intended function of both very ambiguous if I ever inherited the code base. The answer by MaxU is, in terms of the API to me, explicit in what it wants to achieve.

Comment: @roganjosh BTw see the comment I left under MaxU's answer :-)

Comment: I did and upvoted it :) I didn't want to get involved but I did think that was the answer to be accepted. I do find your answer interesting though, it gives me something to read up on, if nothing else but to spot a "gotya" when my code does something unusual :)

Comment: @roganjosh Man , if you know me more, you will find I never ever fight for any point(reputation) related thing in SO. :-)

Comment: @roganjosh I am asking it as an question :-) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944650/replace-value-by-using-regex-to-np-nan