# replace value by using regex to np.nan

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below :

```
data1 = {"first":["alice", "bob", "carol"],
         "last_huge":["foo", "bar", "baz"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
```

For example , I want to replace all character 'o' to 'a':

Then I do

```
df.replace({"o":"a"},regex=True)
Out[668]: 
   first last
0  alice  faa
1    bab  bar
2  caral  baz
```

It give back what I need .

**However**, when I want to replace 'o' to `np.nan` , It will change entire string to `np.nan`. ***Is there any explanation from pandas' document?*** I can find some information through the [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/generic.py#L3678-L3926) .

More Information:(It will change whole string to `np.nan`)

```
df.replace({"o":np.nan},regex=True)
Out[669]: 
   first last
0  alice  NaN
1    NaN  bar
2    NaN  baz
```

Comment: What's you desire result?

Comment: @ShiheZhang there is no desire result , just why replace + regex have this kind of behavior, I can not find any document related to this , only way is to reading thru the source code.

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you on? This actually happens with any non-string object, as far as I can tell, try passing it `object()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga my pandas pd.__version__
Out[692]: '0.20.3'

Comment: you will need to use `for index, row in df.iterrows():` to loop through the df and something like` if(s.contains("0"))` to check if it does. then update the whole value rather than the character

Comment: @JesseBarnett it is successfully when do the character to character replace .question here is when do character to np.nan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NaN is consistently used as a placeholder for missing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17534682/1240268), when replacing part of a string with "missing" it can only mean the entire entry is compromised. I've heard this called NaN pollution (or similar, will see if I can find some references), in that if NaN touches the data is compromised.

That said, that's not always the case:

```
In [11]: s = pd.Series([1, 2, np.nan, 4])

In [12]: s.sum()
Out[12]: 7.0

In [13]: s.sum(skipna=False)
Out[13]: nan
```

In some languages you'll see skipna=False as the default behaviour, some vehemently argue that NaN should *always* pollute all data. Pandas takes a somewhat more pragmatic approach...

The real question is what do you expect it to do in the case of NaN?

Comment: Just like what I am doing with R `sum(.,na.rm=T)`

Comment: For me , I just do not know why they do not give back any error, just replace entire string to `np.nan` ,at least should give back some warning right ...

Comment: Because in python, it's the rightful result, don't need to raise a warning.

Answer (score 1):

In python there are [cmath.nan](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmath.html?highlight=nan#cmath.nan) and [math.nan](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=nan#math.nan).

> CPython implementation detail: The math module consists mostly of thin wrappers around the platform C math library functions. Behavior in exceptional cases follows Annex F of the C99 standard where appropriate. The current implementation will raise ValueError for invalid operations like sqrt(-1.0) or log(0.0) (where C99 Annex F recommends signaling invalid operation or divide-by-zero), and OverflowError for results that overflow (for example, exp(1000.0)). A NaN will not be returned from any of the functions above unless one
>   or more of the input arguments was a NaN; in that case, most functions
>   will return a NaN, but (again following C99 Annex F) there are some
>   exceptions to this rule, for example pow(float('nan'), 0.0) or
>   hypot(float('nan'), float('inf')).

In short word, when your input arguments have `NaN` it would return `NaN`

[And also:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html?highlight=nan#math.nan)

> Note that Python makes no effort to distinguish signaling NaNs from
>   quiet NaNs, and behavior for signaling NaNs remains unspecified.
>   Typical behavior is to treat all NaNs as though they were quiet.