# Replacing looks like range of elements in a column with a set of new values & setting the rest to be 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a data frame I replaced a set of items in a column with a range of values as follows:

```
df['borough_num'] = df['Borough'].replace(regex=['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX'], value=[1, 2, 3, 4,5])
```

The issue that I want to replace all the rest of elements in 'Borough' that not mentioned before with the value 0 also I need to use regex because there are looks like data eg. 07 BRONX, I need it also to be replaced by 5 not 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your previous question , using `replace` , about why it work , you can check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944650/replace-value-by-using-regex-to-np-nan)

```
s=df.Borough.replace(dict(zip(l,[1,2,3,4,5])),regex=True)
pd.to_numeric(s,errors = 'coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[44]: 
0    3
1    5 # notice here still change to 5 
2    1
3    2
4    0
Name: Borough, dtype: int32
```

---

Data Input

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Borough': ['QUEENS', 'BRONX 777', 'MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'INVALID']})
l = ['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even shorter, use `map`:

```
df['borough_num']=df['Borough'].map(dict(zip(['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX'],[1, 2, 3, 4,5])))
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is as expected.

**Update:**

```
df['borough_num']=df['Borough'].str.replace('\d+','').map(dict(zip(['MANHATTAN', 'BROOKLYN', 'QUEENS', 'STATEN ISLAND','BRONX'],[1, 2, 3, 4,5])))
```

Comment: looks like elements such as 07 Bronx shall be replaced by 5 not zero

Comment: @MostafaQasim please accept and up-vote answers when they work, like this one :-), https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I got the real problem @U9-Forward, the modified data has a space before the item , the original element is "BRONX" while the modified by  <<replace('\d+','')>> is stored as " BRONX" note the space before the word, for that reason its not replaced by 5 as its supposed, also we need to add .fillna(0).astype(int) from W-B code so irrelevant elements is replaced by 0 not NAN

Comment: Also @U9-Forward there are some elements such as Unspecified MANHATTAN & Unspecified STATEN ISLAND didn't modified by <<replace('\d+','')>>, If we can split the element name by the first space & take all after the space it may work for all ements