# Change sign of column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input DF:

```
value1, value2
123L, 20
222S, 10
222L, 18
```

I want to make values in volumn `value2` where in `value1` is `L` letter  negative, so I am trying to multiply them by -1

expexted result:

```
value1, value2
    123L, -20
    222S, 10
    222L, -18
```

my code

```
if np.where(DF['value1'].str.contains('L', case=False)):
    DF['value2'] = DF['value2'] * -1
```

but in output i am receiving all values in column `value2` negative.
How to implement this conditions only for selected rows ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Boolean indexing with [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df['value1'].str[-1] == 'L', 'value2'] *= -1
```

Alternatively, using [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df['value2'].mask(df['value1'].str[-1] == 'L', -df['value2'], inplace=True)
```

If you are keen on using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), this is possible but verbose:

```
df['value2'] = np.where(df['value1'].str[-1] == 'L', -df['value2'], df['value2'])
```

Notice `np.where` is already vectorised, you should not use it in conjunction with `if`.

Answer (score 1):

#### `str.endswith` + `loc`

```
df.loc[[x.endswith('L') for x in df.value1], 'value2'] *= -1
df

  value1  value2
0   123L     -20
1   222S      10
2   222L     -18
```

---

#### `mask`

```
df['value2'] = df.value2.mask(df.value1.str.endswith('L'), -df.value2)
df

  value1  value2
0   123L     -20
1   222S      10
2   222L     -18
```

Answer (score 1):

The hack from `replace`  [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944650/replace-value-by-using-regex-to-np-nan)

```
df.value1.replace({'L':-1,'S':1},regex=True)*df.value2.astype(int)
Out[183]: 
0   -20
1    10
2   -18
dtype: int64
```

--

Assign it back

```
df.value2*=df.value1.replace({'L':-1,'S':1},regex=True)
df
Out[187]: 
  value1  value2
0   123L     -20
1   222S      10
2   222L     -18
```