# How to replace the entry of a column with different name by recognizing a pattern?

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column let's say `'Match Place'` in which there are entries like `'MANU @ POR'`, `'MANU vs. UTA'`, `'MANU @ IND'`, `'MANU vs. GRE'` etc. So my columns have 3 things in its entry, the 1st name is `MANU` i.e, 1st country code, 2nd is `@/vs.` and 3rd is again 2nd country name. So what I wanna do is if `'@'` comes in any entry of my column I want is to be changed to `'away'` and if `'vs.'` comes in replace whole entry to `'home'` like 'MANU @ POR' should be changed to `'away'` and 'MANU vs. GRE' should be changed to `'home'`

although I wrote some code to do so using for, if, else but it's taking a way too long time to compute it and my total rows are 30697
so is there any other way to reduce time
below I'm showing you my code
pls help

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    if is_na(df['home/away'][i]) == True:
        temp = (df['home/away'][i]).split()
        if temp[1] == '@':
            df['home/away'][i] = 'away'
        else:
            df['home/away'][i] = 'home
```

Comment: since your first word is always MANU, Your 6th element of string either contains '@' or 'v'. You can use check df['home/away']][i][5] to fasten the process rather than using split.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.select`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+select&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+select&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l4.1884j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to assign multiple conditions:

```
s=df['Match Place'].str.split().str[1] #select the middle element
c1,c2=s.eq('@'),s.eq('vs.') #assign conditions
np.select([c1,c2],['away','home']) #assign this to the desired column
#array(['away', 'home', 'away', 'home'], dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`.str.contains(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to check if the string contains an `@`, and then use [**`.map(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to fill in values accordingly. For example:

```
>>> df
          match
0    MANU @ POR
1  MANU vs. UTA
2    MANU @ IND
3  MANU vs. GRE
>>> df['match'].str.contains('@').map({False: 'home', True: 'away'})
0    away
1    home
2    away
3    home
Name: match, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

use np.where to with contains to check any substring exist or not

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"col1":["manu vs. abc","manu @ pro"]})
df['type'] = np.where(df['col1'].str.contains("@"),"away","home")
```

```
        col1       type
0   manu vs. abc    home
1   manu @ pro      away
```

Answer (score 2):

A fun usage of `replace` more info check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944650/replace-value-by-using-regex-to-np-nan)

```
df['match'].replace({'@':0},regex=True).astype(bool).map({False: 'away', True: 'home'})
0    away
1    home
2    away
3    home
Name: match, dtype: object
```