# Replace Pandas DataFrame column values based on containing dictionary keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, replace

Here is an example, where column is assigned when the row **is** a dictionary key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20250996/12603542

What I am looking for is case, where column is assigned when the row **contains** a dictionary key.

For example (based on example above):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'aba', 1: 'abc', 2: 'abx'}})

#gives me a DataFrame
     col1 
0    aba #contains 'ba'
1    abc #will NOT be replaced
2    abx #contains 'bx'

dictionary = {'ba': 5, 'bx': 8}

#and I need to get:

     col1 
0    5
1    abc
2    8
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with `regex` parameter set to True and pass the mapping dictionary.

```
df.replace(dictionary, regex=True)

#   col2
# 0    5
# 1  abc
# 2    8
```

This usage of `df.replace` is less known. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944650/replace-value-by-using-regex-to-np-nan).

Comment: This is pretty good. +1

Comment: @MayankPorwal Thank you. `df.replace` is very handy, though can be slow at times.

Comment: Some info why this work ~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46944650/replace-value-by-using-regex-to-np-nan

Comment: @BENY Thank you. Added it to my answer as comments might get deleted.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you. I would just add `inplace=True` parameter to the line.